# Form value update on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im making a web app that uses JqueryUI. What I want to happen is to update my `#priceform` upon my resize.
I mean, when i resize the image higher, the price will increment and will decrement when i resize it lower.

Ive tried some code and it seems that my logic wont work in this code.heres my resize code:

```
start:function(event,ui)
                {
                    var height = parseFloat($(".activeElement").find("img").height());
                },


                resize: function(event,ui)
                {   
                    var heightnow = parseFloat($(".activeElement").find("img").height());
                    if(heightnow>height)
                    {

                        price+=pricew;
                        total+=pricew;
                        $("#priceform").val(total);

                    }
                    else if(heightnow<height)
                    {
                        price-=pricew;
                        total-=pricew;
                        $("#priceform").val(total);

                    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you show us some markup?  What is the relationship between the class 'activeElement' and 'img'?  The image is a nested element to whatever element has the 'activeElement' class?  Side note, put a `var` in front of your price and total to scope them down.

Comment: Yes. Thats just for selection purposes. Yea. That's already a var. I just didnt include that line of code.

Comment: Also you have a var in front of `height` in your start method.  That makes it local.  As soon as that method ends it will no longer exist.  So you trying to use it in resize it will be undefined.